# Nodejs High CPU usage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to determine why my nodejs server has extremely high CPU usage. When running top, I can see that the CPU usage for node can hit up to 60% with a single user. I used node-tick to profile my application, but I cannot seem to understand the results well enough to find the source of the problem.

I am using:

```
socket.io
mongodb
jade-templating
express
```

Here are the results:

```
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name 
  31273   88.5%    0.0%  b77b7000-b77b8000
   2144    6.1%    0.0%  /usr/local/bin/node
    269    0.8%    0.0%  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
     45    0.1%    0.0%  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
     13    0.0%    0.0%  2cd46000-2cd47000
     11    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
      2    0.0%    0.0%  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
```

I cannot seem to find this "b77b7000-b77b8000" and google is not yielding many results.

Can anyone determine what is causing my node.js to use so much CPU time?

Comment: **b77b7000-b77b8000** looks like a memory-block to me...?

Comment: @Andy JavaScript != Java; also that URL points to a chinese blog/forum?

Comment: @Diamondo25 it could be. Though, I am not sure what to do with that information.

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) and doing CPU profiling?

Comment: I know, Diamondo25, but it was the only googleable result for `b77b7000` I thought it might have some relevance.

Comment: @mscdex I added a link to those results into the question.

Comment: Simulate high CPU usage - then start to comment out library, dependency of functionality one by one until the CPU usage goes low. Then you know, where you should focus on finding more.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can use a profiler to inspect  performance of  stack function by function.In my option Chrome's is the best one. [Here](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) is a tutorial about how to use it with nodejs

Once you connected debug console to your Chrome debugger you can use performance tab to record a profile for inspection[image: here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

What about the physical memory usage??? Is it normal??

I had the same problem. In my case, CPU and physical memory usage were high. I was trying to bulk insert huge amount of data into the mongo db.

I removed for loops from my code. Then I found a drastic change in the CPU and memory usage. They got reduced to normal rate. For loops increases RAM and CPU usage. It keeps on growing. Like this, Is there anything in your code that uses large amount of memory and cpu??

Comment: Memory usage is at 64mb. So I'd say it looks pretty normal. Page loads are also done within 700ms.